# Restart ruby script after crashing (python)

Tags: python, ruby

I am new to Python. I want to make it show Ruby puts and also to make my ruby script start all over when it crashes:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "ruby script.rb"                                                                          
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)                              
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you paste error?

Comment: No output is printed and the error is of the ruby script not a python one. What I wan ist to print ruby 'puts' and restart the script when it crashes with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Python is a good solution for this problem. It's much better to write a simple CMD (if you're using Windows) or [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) (if you're using Unix-like OS) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap handler SIGINT

RUN=true

handler() {
    RUN=false
}

while [ ${RUN} = true ]; do
    python child.py
done
```

It gives you realtime output, which is much harder to achieve in Python. And automatically restarts script, when it exits.